# ¿Cómo agregar un cuadro dentro de la clase "alert" de bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Buenos días a todos: quisiera pedir su ayuda para obtener lo siguiente.

En la página de Font Awesome, vi sus "alert" y quisiera poder replicarlo. Estoy usando Bootstrap 4.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he podido realizar el recuadro de color amarillo mas oscuro. Si he logrado colocar el ícono. 
Dejo acá el link de [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dbf5hop/) donde está lo que pude hacer... casi nada :(

La imagen la saqué de [acá](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-desktop/setup/getting-started)

Gracias por leer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto una forma que se puede resolver, quizá no sea la mejor pero te puedes guiar.

Primero debemos quitar la clase `alert` a tu `div` y replicar el css y hacerle un par de mejoras, más que nada quitando los paddings y los margin por que se desbalancea el contenido.

Después en lugar de agregar el texto y el icono dentro del `alert` creamos una estructura de columnas, con su debido `row` y `col` eso nos permitirá partir la alerta en dos pedazos independientes y trabajar cada uno de ellos a como nos plazca.

Ya por último sólo agregamos las propiedades que necesitamos en cada uno de ellos. El resultado se vería muy semejante a lo que buscas.

```css
.iconPM {
  animation: blink 2s ease-in infinite;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}

@keyframes blink {

  from,
  to {
    opacity: 0.9
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
}

.alerta{
  position: relative;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br><br>
<div class="shadow bg-white rounded">
  <div class="alert-danger alerta">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1 bg-danger p-3">
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle iconPM"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-11 p-3">
        <h4 class="text-danger text-left">
          Actualmente la carpeta está dada de baja
        </h4>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Puedes jugar con esta respuesta para ver el mejor camino y llegar a como lo quieres exactamente.

Answer (score 2):

Nos podemos valer del uso de *flexbox* para acercarnos al resultado esperado, del modo siguiente:

- Tendremos un `div` principal que englobará tanto un `span` como un `div` interno que servirán para almacenar el área del ícono y del texto
- Hacemos que el contenedor tenga hijos *flexibles* con el uso de *flexbox*
- Después el `span` que contiene el icono de alerta le aplicamos también que sus hijos en este caso el texto sean flexibles para de este modo centrarlo vertical y horizontalmente
- Al `span` que contiene el icono de alerta le damos un ancho de 10% para simular el diseño que tiene en la imagen

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        body {
          font-size: .8em;
        }
        .alert {
          display: flex;
          background: #FFF9DB;
        }
        .alert-parrafo {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        .alert-icon {
          background: #FFE066;
          width: 10%;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        .titulo {
          font-weight: bold;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="alert">
      <span class="alert-icon">Icono</span>
      <div class="alert-parrafo">
       <p class="titulo">Heads Up! Breaking changes in version 5.7.0</p>
       <p>We fixed some issues with using our OTF and TTF font files on mobile projects. After updating your font files, double-check that your icons are rendering as expected.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Gracias por comentar!!. Las dos opciones me gustan, ahora me pongo a trabajar para llevarlo a práctica!! Gracias